# Bower install an ignored file

Tags: bower

I would like my code to include just one file from nvd3. I could just grab that file and include it in my source directly. But I wanted to have it loaded automatically as a bower dependency.

`bower info nvd3` shows that all the individual src files will be ignored. bower install is going to give me to whole library. I don't suppose there's a way to say in my bower.json something like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "nvd3": { 
        "version": "~1.1.15-beta",
        "ignore": ["all the stuff I don't want", "**/*"],
        "but-include": ["that one src file I still want", "src/models/tooltip.js"]
}
```

Just thought I'd ask.

But, assuming this is impossible, should I just put the file in my source, or is there some better way. Like depend on the path to that file in the GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Bower Installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer).  You can use it to basically pull all the required files for a package into  a folder of your choice using your `bower.json` file.

Sample syntax

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "dependencies" : {
    "backbone" : "latest",
    "requirejs" : "latest"
  },
  "install" : {
    "path" : "some/path",
    "sources" : {
      "requirejs" : "bower_components/requirejs/require.js"
    }
  }
}
```